# How to get column name which contains certain string

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with the below columns/values

```
d1   d2   d3   d4   d5
10   12   9    2    6
```

i couldn't figure out how to get column name for the matching value... as the query should return   `d1`  if the matched value is  `10`. i just simply i want the column name to be returned for the matched value

this is the orders listing query.. the problem with this query is that it returns all pending orders for all departments. but if i added  AND `stage` = 'd1' i will work 
i just don't know how to get 'd1' or 'd2' 'd3' from the layout i demonstrated

```
SELECT `phoenix_so`.`id`, `stage`, `so_number`, `service` AS service_id, `cid`, `uid`, `pec`, `customer_name`, `phoenix_so_service`.`name` AS service, `location`, `phoenix_so_priority`.`name` AS pri, `phoenix_so_priority`.`css_class`, `phoenix_so_type`.`name` as type, `phoenix_so_type`.`css_class` AS type_css
FROM (`phoenix_so`)
LEFT JOIN `phoenix_so_service` ON `phoenix_so`.`service` = `phoenix_so_service`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `phoenix_so_priority` ON `phoenix_so`.`priority` = `phoenix_so_priority`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `phoenix_so_type` ON `phoenix_so`.`type` = `phoenix_so_type`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `phoenix_so_roadmap` ON `phoenix_so`.`service` = `phoenix_so_roadmap`.`service_id`
WHERE `inv_access_cdate` = "0000-00-00"
```

Comment: Why do you want this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: you see 'd1' and 'd2' etc are the stages of a service order and the numbers below is the departments number that is currently processing the order. so when the corresponding users logs in to their page they should see list of orders that is awaiting them..
i will post the listing query in the main post